# geodesic dome strut length with connector

Tags: geodesic

I want to build a geodesic dome for meditating...

Im gonna have a 1mt radius dome,

according to calculations done in [geodesic dome calculator](http://www.byexample.net/library/calculators/geodesic_dome_calculator/index.html?domeRadius=1&domeUnits=meters) this is what i need:

> To build a 2V Dome with a radius of 1 meters requires:
>   35 Struts 0.62 meters each
>   30 Struts 0.55 meters each
>   26 Bolts, 26 Nuts, & 52 Washers
>   Total of about 40 meters of Conduit

I will be using pvc pipe, with this kind of connector [a bigger pvc pipe]

[image]
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iw86uYBhqN4 [pvc pipe used as connector]

so the question is:
 how much should I take of the length of the struts if im gonna use for the connectors PVC of 15 mm  [[actual outside diameter 20mm]](http://www.bunnings.com.au/holman-15mm-1m-press-pvc-pipe-class-18-pvp1518-1_p4750046)

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you build something with radius 20cm out of smaller, narrower materials, and see what happens. I think that is big enough that your hands will be able to fit inside while putting it together.

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about geodesics, is that **symmetry is king!**

So, it **makes no difference** what size of pipe you use as your joint hub (within reason), just as long as you **use the same size for hub everywhere!**

**IMPORTANT**:  Initially, don't tighten the zips all the way.  Tighten them until you have a bit of "wiggle".  If too tight, you won't be able to gets struts to tilt at correct angles for various joints.

Do the bottom circumference first, and work your way up. Tighten the side-oriented connectors, but not those at the top, until you have the struts in place there.

You will get the feel for it as you work "up the ladder" of dome strut levels.

Hope that clarifies!